# Google+ share plugin - I cannot get the desired image to be displayed in my +1 update

Tags: google-plus

I'm using the Google+ share plugin which simultaneously does a +1 and a share.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the image that I specify to appear.

I was using an image that is 200px by 200px which complies with the size requirements. I can get the name and the description to display as specified.

The following is the code that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Vacancy">
<head>

<meta itemprop="name" content="Vacancy">
<meta itemprop="description" content="A new job vacancy etc">
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBafMb42NGLi-C-NEmdC-RQDJ5t8PRahD4uTdpOuSAnD5_gMU1_g">

</head>

<body> 

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>


<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

All works fine except that the correct image is not displayed on the +1 share.

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Mary

Comment: G+ may have just cached a version without the image and that is what you are seeing. You might just have to wait a little while until the cache expires.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've supplied is working for me. An image of a cat that is 160px square is showing up in your snippet.

[image: a screen shot of snippet]

Comment: Hi Jenny, I see that it's working now. When I tried it, it didn't work. I'm new to these meta tags. Is there some delay in the image being made available to google+. Is there any restriction on the file types that can be used? Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated. Many thanks, Mary

Comment: It sounds like you may have been seeing a cached version of the page.  The server which fetches your page and generates the snippet will respect any cache directives you set. As a result if you click on the button and then change the page, you may still see the old content in the snippet. To work around this use short cache timeouts during development :)